# Не срабатывает on jquery?

Tags: jquery

Почему такая конструкция не срабатывает:

```
$('#FormComment #sendComment, #SendReplyComment').on('click', function(e) });
```

А такая работает:

```
$('#FormComment #sendComment, #SendReplyComment').live('click', function(e) });
```

Comment: Если элемент добавляется на страницу динамически, то нужно использовать live.

Comment: @zghenyab live устарел

Comment: @zghenyab .on() также подходит для случаев, когда элемент добавляется динамически. И как заметили уже выше - .live() с версии 1.9 удалён.

Comment: Это с версии 1.7, а если предположить, что у @junart древняя версия jquery, то мой ответ верный?!

Comment: я думаю у него on, работает, просто live не удален. если версия более древняя чем 1.7 то надо мигрировать а не адаптироваться под нее, почитайте в relis notes что дало .on() в плане прироста производительности в jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вы используете старую версию jQuery. .on() стал поддерживаться с версии 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

чтобы использовать  on в виде .live, вам нужно пользоваться конструкцией

```
parentelement.on('event','selector',function);
```

видимо в вашем случае хотелось

```
$(document).on('click','#FormComment #sendComment, #SendReplyComment' function(e) {});
```

**но**

вы видимо используете множественные ID - это противоречит стандартам html, лучше поменяйте их на class

и делайте так

```
$(document).on('click','.FormComment .sendComment, #SendReplyComment', function(e){} );
```

так-же если ваши добавляемые элементы находятся в неком статичном элементе, то вместо **`$(document)`** используйте что-то типа **`$('.myparentelementselector')`**. Еще в моем последнем примере я предположил что **`#SendReplyComment`** - единственный элемент в документе.